# How to express sin(y) in terms of cos(y)?

Tags: trigonometry

The first question asked to express a equivalent expression in of $\cos(x+y)$ for which I got right.

However its the second part of the question that I do not understand which is How to express $\sin(y)$ in terms of $\cos(y)$? also the angle between $0$ and $\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin { y } =\cos { \left( y-\frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  \right)  } \\$$
or $$ \sin { y=\sqrt { 1-\cos ^{ 2 }{ y }  }  } $$

Answer (score 2):

Recall the Pythagorean identity:

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Divide both sides by $c^2$:

$$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$$

Solve for $\sin$.